# Routing of a multipleChoiceItem question with multiple sections, google-apps-script google-forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, page-break

***Hi beautiful people***

I'm having issues in google apps script, trying to generate a google form with several pages, one of which beeing a multiple-choice question.

I succesfully set up the routing to different sections depending of the answer to the question.
The issue i'm facing is the last go-to: i need the user to be redirected out of the multiple-choice question sections after completing one section.

For now, let's say I answered with the first answer, I will be redirected to the first sub-section, but then I will have to go trough the second and third sub-sections as well, despite them beeing linked to other answers.

I want to set up a goto to the next page at the end of each subsection, to skip the other ones, but idk how.

Here is a simplified version of my current script :

```
// Setting up the multipleChoiceItem:
let mci = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle("Question")
      .setRequired(true) 
    
  // Setting up the sub-sections
  var sectionOne = form.addPageBreakItem()
      .setTitle("First Section")
      .setHelpText("This is the first section");

    form.addTextItem().setTitle("Question inside section one").setRequired(true);


  var sectionTwo = form.addPageBreakItem()
      .setTitle("Second section")
      .setHelpText("This is the second section");

    form.addTextItem().setTitle("Questio inside section two").setRequired(true);


  var sectionThree = form.addPageBreakItem()
      .setTitle("Third section")
      .setHelpText("This is the third section");

    form.addTextItem().setTitle("Question inside section three").setRequired(true);
     
    
  // linking the sections to the answers
  mci.setChoices([
    mci.createChoice("first answer", sectionOne),
    mci.createChoice("second answer", sectionTwo),
    mci.createChoice("third answer", sectionThree)
  ]);


// The next page and the rest of the form   
var nextPage = form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle("The next page")
    .setHelpText("This is the next page I would need to be redirected to after answering to any subsections of the mci");
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with pageBreakItems and GO_TO_PAGE, something that could look like this:

```
  sectionOne.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.GO_TO_PAGE(nextPage));
```

but I can't get it to work, it seems like the GO_TO_PAGE method was never really implemented, there is little to none info about it in the doc.

Anyway, I hope that someone has figured it out, I would appreciate a little help!

**Thanks a lot mates !**

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Also no need for the loveydovey mate/bro/dude ;)

Comment: @ElPaul Were you able to accomplish what you want manually  in the Google forms user interface? If so, this is possible with script. If not, it won't be possible with script. Try to do this with the UI first.

Comment: @TheMaster yep in the forms UI this is pretty straight forward, each question / section has the "what to do next" drop down menu, in which you can select any page of the entire form, including "past" or "future" ones.
That's exactly what I would need to set from my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to Copilot i got it figured out, turns out I was pretty close, but it was pretty difficult to get it to work dued to the lack of documentation on this very topic.

This is what it would look like:

```
// Setting up the multipleChoiceItem:
let mci = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle("Question")
      .setRequired(true) 
    
// Setting up the sub-sections
var sectionOne = form.addPageBreakItem()
      .setTitle("First Section")
      .setHelpText("This is the first section");

form.addTextItem().setTitle("Question inside section one").setRequired(true);


var sectionTwo = form.addPageBreakItem()
      .setTitle("Second section")
      .setHelpText("This is the second section");

form.addTextItem().setTitle("Questio inside section two").setRequired(true);


var sectionThree = form.addPageBreakItem()
      .setTitle("Third section")
      .setHelpText("This is the third section");

form.addTextItem().setTitle("Question inside section three").setRequired(true);
     
    
// linking the sections to the answers
mci.setChoices([
    mci.createChoice("first answer", sectionOne),
    mci.createChoice("second answer", sectionTwo),
    mci.createChoice("third answer", sectionThree)
]);


// The next page and the rest of the form   
var nextPage = form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle("The next page")
    .setHelpText("This is the next page I would need to be redirected to after answering to any subsections of the mci");

// [rest of the form]

// Routing to the next page after each answer section
sectionOne.setGoToPage(nextPage);
sectionTwo.setGoToPage(nextPage);
sectionThree.setGoToPage(nextPage);
```